# Closure of Interior and Interior of Closure

Tags: general-topology

I know questions similar to this have been asked here but, is it possible to find a subset of a topological space such that its closure of interior and interior of closure does not contain each other? 
For example if $X=\mathbb{R}$, $A=\mathbb{Q}$, the closure of interior of A would be contained in the interior of closure of A.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "does not contain **each other**?" That neither contains the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example inside $\Bbb{R}$ is
$$A=([0,1] \cap \Bbb{Q}) \cup [2,3]$$
the interior of the closure of $A$ is $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$, while the closure of the interior is $[2,3]$: these two sets are not comparable by inclusion.